# How do I return my List as a DataSource to a dropdown list control

Tags: c#, asp.net

I create a list of strings called myList.  I have a DropDownList control called ddlStrings that I need populated with the list. How do I programmatically do this?

```
ddlStrings.DataSource = // This is where I am trying to set the dataSource of my DropDownList
if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtBox1.Text))
{
    try
    { 
      //I removed some irrelevant logic here


        List<String> myList = new List<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < foo.bar.Length; i++)
        {
            myList.Add(foo.bar[i].Value);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
```

Comment: Set the datasource = myList and call ddlStrings.DataBind() of course after inserting values in the myList

Comment: Now you are telling us a different story

Comment: For a ComboBox, you will need to implement a class that has a `Text` and `Value` property. Text is for visual and value is what is selected or like an ID. You add the `List` of this class to the ComboBox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the items and assign them as the control's datasource like so:

```
List<String> stringsToAssign = Bla.ToList();
checkListBoxStrings.DataSource = stringsToAssign;
```

If you assign a custom class to the combobox, you can also take advantage of separate display and value members, like so (assuming your custom class is named "Student" which has members named "FullName" and "StudentID"):

```
List<Student> studentsToAssign = Bla.ToList();
checkListBoxStudents.DataSource = studentsToAssign;
checkListBoxStudents.DisplayMember = "FullName";
checkListBoxStudents.ValueMember = "StudentID";
```